# Why I am getting Exception sending a message when starting Gazebo and how to solve it?

Tags: gazebo-9

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I have ROS melodic and Gazebo 9 in my system.
When I type

```
gazebo
```

in my terminal, I am getting following message:

```
Exception sending a message
```

that keeps on printing in terminal console.

How should I resolve this issue?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/20028/why-i-am-getting-exception-sending-a-message-when-starting-gazebo-and-how-to-solve-it?/) by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 53 on 2018-07-18

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Raskkii](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/4131/raskkii/) on 2018-07-18**:
Could you try launching it like this to see if anything changes: rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo --verbose

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2018-07-19**:
Surprisingly, I didn't encounter this exception message today, either with your proposed method or just by typing 'gazebo' in command line. I wonder why it happened.

**Comment by [rahul](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/2334/rahul/) on 2018-07-24**:
Hi @Raskkii , today I encountered this problem again and it occurs even when I type
`rosrun gazebo_ros gazebo --verbose`

**Comment by [Sietse](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6373/sietse/) on 2018-08-27**:
Same here, but don't use ros with it. The only special thing is that my home directory is nfs mounted.

**Comment by [aray](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7284/aray/) on 2018-11-17**:
same here also. ros melodic + gazebo 9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I also ran into this problem. This happens only when I open a VPN connection. Setting the environment variable `IGN_IP` to `127.0.0.1` solved this problem. Here is [the discussion](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/21103/exception-sending-a-message/)

---

Originally posted by [aray](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/7284/aray/) with karma: 76 on 2019-04-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ticotico](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/48032/ticotico/) on 2021-05-29**:
thx a lot! (would upvote if I could :))